# Is new T() equivalent to `mem = operator new(sizeof(T)); new(mem)T`?

Tags: c++

Basically, my question is whether the following code is valid.

```cpp
void* mem = operator new(sizeof(T));
T* instance = new(mem) T;
delete instance;
```

If it isn’t, I’d be curious to know whether there is a way to split allocation and initialization for an object that is going to be deleted through `delete obj;`.

Comment: Is `std::allocator` the thing you want?

Comment: I find the question interesting. I'm also curious: would there be a practical use case?

Comment: @JohnDing No. I’m fairly sure that the default allocator uses operator new() + placement new under the hood, and does the “classical” reverse of that process by calling the destructor explicitly before deallocating.

Comment: @eerorika This is motivated by a real problem, yes – basically, our codebase is using `delete ptr;` in a way that would be hard to move away from (although doable), but I’m in a situation where I need an object’s address before I can actually construct it to avoid a chicken-and-egg issue with a library we’re using.

Comment: @Peter I know that. Your comment is not helpful here.

Comment: you could perhaps create a class-member operator delete, unless you have a lot of classes

Comment: @sp2danny Thank you, that’s helpful! I’ll keep it in mind as a fallback if this doesn’t turn out to work.

Comment: During a `delete p` expression, any class member `operator delete` involved is called after the destructor finishes, so I don't see how that would help.

Comment: They differ in the cases of allocation failing, and T's constructor throwing an exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does appear to be valid, as long as `T` is not an array type, and is not a class with a custom `operator delete` visible from its scope which is incompatible with the `operator new` you invoke.

[[expr.delete]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.delete#2) says the operand of `delete` may be "a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*". The *new-expression* grammar syntax symbol does include the placement new syntax, and [expr.delete] doesn't say the previous *new-expression* needs to be a non-placement variety. And any *new-expression* including a placement new is considered to "create" an object.

The `operator new` allocation function and `operator delete` deallocation function involved do need to match up. `operator new(sizeof(T))` will normally call the global ordinary allocation function, but to be more sure you can write `::operator new(sizeof(T))`. The deallocation function is looked up in the scope of class `T`, so a `static operator delete(void*);` in a class could break this.

You might want to consider exception safety, though. A straight `T* p = ::new T;` is actually more equivalent to:

```
void* mem = ::operator new(sizeof(T));
T* p;
try {
    p = ::new(mem) T;
} catch (...) {
    ::operator delete(mem, sizeof(T));
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.delete#8) makes this clear.

(Also, we build with `-fno-exceptions`, but you’re right of course – thanks again!)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is given almost exactly in the same form, as an explicit example, in the C++ standard:

> 21.6.2.3 Non-allocating forms           [new.delete.placement]
>
> void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
>
> Returns: ptr.
>
> Remarks: Intentionally performs no other action.
>
> ```
>      [ Example: This can be useful for constructing an object at a known
>      address:
>
>      void* place = operator new(sizeof(Something));
>      Something* p = new (place) Something();
>
>      — end example ]
> ```

Add a delete, after that, and you get what you wrote in your question.

Comment: You can't use `delete instance;` on memory allocated with `placement-new`, you have to call the `instance'`s destructor directly instead, and then free the memory separately as needed, eg: `void* mem = operator new(sizeof(T)); T* instance = new(mem) T; ... 
instance->~T(); operator delete(mem);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The point of my question was whether you actually *do* need to call the constructor directly if the allocation function is `operator new(size_t)`. As the other answer explains, it’s not necessary.